# C++ Bubble sort users fname and lname alphabetically from a file using a function

Tags: c++, function, file, bubble-sort

I just need to figure out the two commented sections i added and I think Ill be able to finish the rest of it. I am new at coding so I apologize for the sloppy format.I appreciate the chance to perhaps learn something new from you guys. I need more details to type out so I am going to type this until I reach the character li

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

void fileCheck(ifstream& zFile, string filen);
int getData(ifstream& zFile, string txt[]);
void sortData(string text[], int counter);

 



int main()
{
ifstream zFile1;
ifstream zFile2;


zFile1.open("firstname.txt");
zFile2.open("lastname.txt");

fileCheck(zFile1,"firstname.txt");
fileCheck(zFile2,"lastname.txt");

string fName[100], lName[100];
int fcounter = getData(zFile1, fName);
int lcounter = getData(zFile2, lName);

for (int a = 0; a < fcounter; a++)
{
    cout << "Name: " << fName[a] << " " << lName[a] << endl << endl;
    

}

string text[100];
ifstream zFile;
zFile.open("fName.txt");
int counter;
counter = getData(zFile, text);

sortData(text, counter);
zFile1.close();
zFile2.close();
return 0;
```

}

```
void fileCheck(ifstream& zFile, string filen)
{
if (!zFile.is_open())
{
    cout << filen << " not found" << endl;
    exit(1);

}
```

}

```
int getData(ifstream& zFile, string txt[])
{
int counter = 0;
while (!zFile.eof())
{
    getline(zFile, txt[counter]);
    counter++;

}
return counter;
```

}

```
void sortData(string text[], int counter) //I know I need something here after counter
{
string temp;

for (int a = 0; a < counter; a++)
{

    for (int b = 0; b < counter-1; b++)
    {
        if (text[b] > text[b + 1])
        {
            temp = text[b + 1];
            text[b + 1] = text[b];
            text[b] = temp;

                             //and one thing here too I think
                            
        }
        
    }



}
```

}

Comment: What is wrong with `sortData`, in your opinion? Why do you believe it needs corrections? I don't see anything fatally wrong with it. It's not the most efficient, and it's not quite bubble sort, but it should get the array sorted all right.

Comment: Hello Igor, Thanks for taking the time to respond. I am really super new at coding so my opinions aren't very backed in facts. What I am trying to do here is have the function sortData alphabetically by using the counter to check each string text in a given file. I then am going to display the names from A-Z or Z-A(however I do not need help with that just this if any insight can be given.) I have been looking at bubble sort videos/text for hours trying to troubleshoot my issue so I appreciate you. It does not currently sorta the file alphabetically yet.

Comment: How do you know `sortData` doesn't sort the array passed to it? What makes you believe that? What evidence do you have of that?

Comment: I complied it using Visual Studios and but an A name at the bottom and it output as a list not as an alphabetical list

Comment: The program shown prints `fName` and `lName` a) before `sortData` call, and b) these aren't passed to `sortData` anyway. Do you expect `sortData` to magically change the output already printed, of the data that wasn't even passed to it?

Comment: Ah like I said this is only my 3rd week programming so I really don't grasp these concepts as easy as you do. I can see that I am going to a lot more work on my understanding because I grasp what you are saying but not how to implement it. Ignor, I wont take anymore of your time thank you so much for answering my question, you rock man!